# Is there a way to establish Bluetooth Connection between iOS 6 and iOS7?

Tags: ios, ios6, ios7, bluetooth

Is there a way to establish Bluetooth Connection between iOS 6 and iOS7 ? I have implemented BluetoothConnectivity Using GameKit (GKSeesion) Frame earlier in iOS6 but now Apple has ommitted it in iOS7 and has provided Multipeer Connectivity (MCSession) Framework. So is there any solution to make connection using GKSession and MCSession? Can anyone kindly guide me the right path to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

For now you can still use GKSession. In another 6 months-1 year update the App for only iOS7 devices and convert to MCSession.  By that time >90% of users will be on iOS7.